# data fetching error in next.js [getServerside Method]

Tags: reactjs, next.js

This is my folder structure:

```
project-root
├── pages
│   ├── Header.js

├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── layout.js
│   │   ├── page.js
│   └── ...
├── ...
```

pages/Header.js

```js
import React from "react";

function ProductsPage({ products }) {
  console.log(products);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Products</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const products = await response.json();

  return {
    props: {
      products
    }
  };
}

export default ProductsPage;
```

But the output shows `undefined`. Please anyone tell me what to do.